# Is the following sentence a correct?

Tags: past-tense

Is the following sentence correct?

> Are you seeing movies in your free time.

I want to ask my friend whether he watches English movies in his free time .

Comment: Hi Aakash, unless your sentence has a valid source, it will be considered as '**Proofreading**'. Proofreading something isn't encouraged here, on ELL.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need past tense to ask this question, unless you're asking about a specific time in the past.

> 'Do you watch movies in your spare time?'

...would be an appropriate question.

Comment: Agreed.  Also "are you Xing" has an implication of "...right now", which doesn't fit with with "in your spare time".